# What is the difference between mutate+push and update+spread?

Tags: angular, signals

Let's say you have a `Signal` for an array of items and you want to add new values to this array. There are two ways to approach it:

```
// A: using mutate to mutate it in place and invoking the push method
items$.mutate(items => items.push(newItem))

// B: using update to create a new item with the spread operator
items$.update(items => [...items, item])
```

Are there any practical differences that should be considered between these two approaches? Or does it all comes down to semantics, personal preference and performance?

Comment: I would suggest looking at the implementation.
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/core/src/signals/src/signal.ts#L95


One difference I see is that using mutate you bypass the equality check. So, using when using update consumers are only notified if the newValue is not equal to the currentValue. Whereas mutate will still notify consumers also if the newValue is the same. I am sure there are also other subtle differences.

Answer (score 0):

One practical difference that comes to mind is that you can't use the OnPush Strategy when using mutate.

Comment: Without having tried it, I would assume it'd work. You're explicitly saying that you will mutate the value.